# Remove NA from a dataframe column R

Tags: r, regex, string, dataframe, na

I have a dataframe named Resultaat

```
Cluster Number
W63     1020 NA NA NA 1100
W50     1020 NA 1240 NA NA
```

I want to remove all the NA values en keep the numbers. The columns are defined as character.

Expected output

```
Cluster Number
W63     1020 1100
W50     1020 1240
```

I tried things like
`gsub("^NA(?:\\s+NA)*\\b\\s*|\\s*\\bNA(?:\\s+NA)*$", "", Resultaat$Number)`
& `Resultaat <- Resultaat[!is.na(Resultaat)]` but nothing works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option - read the column 'Number' with `read.table` and `unite` all the columns, excluding the `NA` elements with `na.rm = TRUE`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
read.table(text = Resultaat$Number, header = FALSE, fill = TRUE) %>% 
  unite(Number, everything(), na.rm = TRUE, sep = " ") %>% 
  bind_cols(Resultaat[1], .)
```

-output

```
Cluster    Number
1     W63 1020 1100
2     W50 1020 1240
```

---

Regarding the `gsub`, it can be

```
gsub("\\s+NA|NA\\s+|NA$|^NA", "", Resultaat$Number)
[1] "1020 1100" "1020 1240"
```

---

Or may also use `tidvyerse` methods as

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
Resultaat %>%
   separate_rows(Number) %>% 
   na_if("NA") %>%
   drop_na() %>%
   group_by(Cluster) %>%
   summarise(Number = str_c(Number, collapse = " "))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  Cluster Number   
  <chr>   <chr>    
1 W50     1020 1240
2 W63     1020 1100
```

#### data

```
Resultaat <- structure(list(Cluster = c("W63", "W50"), 
Number = c("1020 NA NA NA 1100", 
"1020 NA 1240 NA NA")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: There was a comment which I didn't see

Comment: Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 3 did not have 175 elements.

\Is there a problem with my data?

Comment: @TimoV use `fill = TRUE` (updated)

Comment: new error: 
Error in `stop_vctrs()`:
! Can't recycle `..1` (size 236) to match `..2` (size 288).
My real df is 236 long

Comment: @TimoV Not clear about that error though.  Can you try the updated `gsub` option

Comment: Amazing, gsub is working
Thnx a lot @akrun

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all numbers and NAs are space separated:

```
library("tidyverse")

Resultaat$Number <- Resultaat$Number %>% 
  str_split(pattern = " ") %>% 
  map_chr(~ paste(.x[.x != "NA"], collapse = " "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option with `regmatches` with pattern `[^(NA) ]+`

```
transform(
  df,
  Number = sapply(
    regmatches(
      Number,
      gregexpr("[^(NA) ]+", Number)
    ),
    paste0,
    collapse = " "
  )
)
```

which gives

```
  Cluster    Number
1     W63 1020 1100
2     W50 1020 1240
```